# Reading the running process from OS and displaying it through C++!

Tags: c++, process, operating-system

This code will read the running process from OS and display it (C++). Specifically, the OS here is Windows XP. The Problem(error) is in (i think) prototype. By the way, it displays following errors.

**Error 1 : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumProcesses@12 referenced in function _main**

**Error 2 : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetModuleBaseNameA@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl DisplayProcessNameAndID(unsigned long)" (?DisplayProcessNameAndID@@YAXK@Z)**

**Error 3 : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumProcessModules@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl DisplayProcessNameAndID(unsigned long)" (?DisplayProcessNameAndID@@YAXK@Z)**

**Error 4 : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals C:\Documents and Settings\Windows\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\a\Debug\a.exe**

```
#include <afxwin.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "psapi.h"
unsigned int i;

using namespace std;
void DisplayProcessNameAndID(DWORD processID);
void main()
{

   DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
   if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
      return;
   cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);


   for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
   {
   if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
          DisplayProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
   }
};
void DisplayProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
   TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID ) ;`                                                                     

   if (NULL != hProcess )
   {
      HMODULE hMod;
      DWORD cbNeeded;
      if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded) )
      {
         GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
            sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
      }
   };
   CString str;
   str.Format("Text:%s, PID : %u", szProcessName, processID );
   AfxMessageBox(str);
   CloseHandle( hProcess );
   }
```

Comment: Your windows.h is C?  If so, you may need an extern "C" to prevent C++ name-mangling from screwing up your linker.

Comment: I have to do nothing with windows.h. Hence i removed it. It make no difference.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to add "psapi.lib" to the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your issue is not with the prototype - the prototypes in windows.h are fine.  If you notice your error message start with `LNK` which means that the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) is giving the error.  This means that the linker can't find those functions.

If you look at the documentation for one of the functions that is giving the error, [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the very bottom in the `Library` section you'll see that on Windows XP it requires linking to `Psapi.lib`.  Visual C++ doesn't link to that library by default like it does for `Kernel32.lib`, which is why any functions defined in that library are fine.

You can add the `Psapi.lib` to the `Additional Libraries` section of your project, or just add the line:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")
```

To the top of the file, which will instruct the linker to use Psapi.lib.

Comment: Then what the problem?

Comment: @Jamel - I hit save accidentally before I was finished.  Give a moment to finish my answer.